# How to draw the clock cycle number to the rising edge?

Tags: tikz-pgf, counters, tikz-timing

I want to display the number of every clock cycle at the rising edge. I tried to setting a counter but it gives me this error:

```
Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/timing/counter/new', to wnd I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it. ... ,text style={font=\scriptsize}}] 18{c} \\$
```

Here the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}
\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}
\usepackage{pgf}

\usepgflibrary{arrows} % for pgf-umlsd

\begin{document}
\begin{tikztimingtable}[
    timing/dslope=0.1,
    timing/.style={x=7ex,y=2ex},
    x=5ex,
    timing/rowdist=3ex,
    timing/name/.style={font=\sffamily\scriptsize},
]
    CLK       &  [timing/counter/new={char=c,max value=15, wraps ,text style={font=\scriptsize}}] 18{c} \\
    GNT       & L N(A1) 8H \\
    FRAME     & U 6L H U \\
    AD   & 2u 1D{Adresse} 1U{} 1D{$d_1$} D{$d_1 '$} D{$d_2$} 2D{$d_3$} U \\
    C/BE & 2u 1D{0010} 6D{BE\#} U  \\
    IRDY       & UU 4L HLH \\
    TRDY       & UU HLH 3L H \\
    DEVSEL     & 2U 6L H\\
\end{tikztimingtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Please can you complete your code so we have a compilable document? I have no idea what I need to make this so I can compile it in order to help. I figure maybe `standalone` for class and presumably `tikz` but, beyond that, I'm clueless.

Comment: I found a timing/counter/opt/max value and a timing/new counter/new in the source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the documentation, `timing/counter/new` is provided by the `counters` library. So you need to load that library:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}
\usetikztiminglibrary{counters}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikztimingtable}[
    timing/dslope=0.1,
    timing/.style={x=7ex,y=2ex},
    x=5ex,
    timing/rowdist=3ex,
    timing/name/.style={font=\sffamily\scriptsize},
    ]
    CLK       & [timing/counter/new={char=c,max value=15, wraps ,text style={font=\scriptsize}}] 18{c} \\
    GNT       & L N(A1) 8H \\
    FRAME     & U 6L H U \\
    AD   & 2u 1D{Adresse} 1U{} 1D{$d_1$} D{$d_1 '$} D{$d_2$} 2D{$d_3$} U \\
    C/BE & 2u 1D{0010} 6D{BE\#} U  \\
    IRDY       & UU 4L HLH \\
    TRDY       & UU HLH 3L H \\
    DEVSEL     & 2U 6L H\\
  \end{tikztimingtable}
\end{document}
```

[image: new counter for timing]